# Changing all button colors with a single function tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

so im trying to define a function which changes the color of all buttons avaiable in the program without having to config each one separately, something that looks like this:

```
def change_colors():
    #change button a, b and c colors

a = Button(text='1',command=change_color)
b = Button(text='2',command=change_color)
c = Button(text='3',command=change_color)
```

in this example i can just do:

```
def change_colors():
    a.config(bg='red')
    b.config(bg='red')
    c.config(bg='red')
```

but in my actual code there's alot of buttons and each button needs to do a diffrent color

Comment: If each button needs a different color, what's stopping you from giving each button a different color?

Comment: @BryanOakley I assume OP wants the color to change when the button is clicked

Comment: It is not clear what you want.  Do you want, for example, 1) when button 1 is clicked, the background color of *all buttons* will be changed to "red" (or other color); 2) when button 2 is clicked, the background color of *all buttons* will be changed to "blue" (or other color)?

Comment: @acw1668 They say "each button needs to do a different color" which I took to mean "change each individual button to a given color" but yeah, that could just as easily mean "change all the buttons to the color assigned to <Button X>". OP, can you please clarify what exactly you're after?

Comment: Typo error should be `command=change_colors` instead of `command=change_color`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to handle this by leveraging `lambda`s (a.k.a. "anonymous functions")

- define each `tk.Button` widget like you would normally
- use `config` to set their `command` property after defining them (because you'll need to reference the buttons themselves, so they have to be created first!)
- use a `lambda` to pass the button object and a color to a function that handles the color change (the lambda is used to pass dynamic arguments to the function)

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()


def change_btn_color(btn: tk.Button, color: str) -> None:
    btn.config(bg=color)


a = tk.Button(text='1')
a.config(command=lambda: change_btn_color(a, 'red'))
a.pack()

b = tk.Button(text='2')
b.config(command=lambda: change_btn_color(b, 'green'))
b.pack()

c = tk.Button(text='3')
c.config(command=lambda: change_btn_color(c, 'blue'))
c.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

---

If the goal instead is to change **ALL** of the buttons to the color assigned to a given button, the approach changes just a little.

Here, `change_btn_color` gets all of the widgets in the `root` window, and then changes the widget's color if that widget is a `tk.Button`.

Using this approach, you can set the `command` as you define each `Button` - there's no need for the separate call to `config` because you're not passing in the buttons themselves in this case.

Again, we're making use of a `lambda` so we can pass in an argument (a color name) to the `command` function.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()


def change_btn_color(color: str) -> None:
    for widget in root.winfo_children():  # get all the widgets
        if isinstance(widget, tk.Button):  # get only the buttons
            widget.config(bg=color)


a = tk.Button(text='1', command=lambda: change_btn_color('red'))
a.pack()

b = tk.Button(text='2', command=lambda: change_btn_color('green'))
b.pack()

c = tk.Button(text='3', command=lambda: change_btn_color('blue'))
c.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Any time - happy to help!